# How do I make a tipfy app accept own-auth, OpenID, and more?

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, tipfy

Tipfy's [user-authentication tutorial](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/tutorials/auth/) advertises its unified system that accepts all of Google, own-auth, OpenID, OAuth, and Facebook authentication; but the examples so far show exclusively Google auth and exclusively own-auth.

How do I make the other authentication options available?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851536/authentication-using-any-openid-with-tipfy/4851820#4851820

Answer (score 3):

There's now an example showing several authentication methods used at the same time [here](http://tipfy-auth.appspot.com/). Source code is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy-ext-auth/source/browse/#hg/examples/multi-auth).